# My Macbook 7.1 (Macbook white mid-2010) 10gb ram, 250gb SSD Samsung 850 EVO overheats with few apps open

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, temperature

My Macbook 7.1 (Macbook white mid-2010) with 10gb ram and 250gb SSD Samsung 850 EVO overheats with very few apps open. It overheats for no particular reason. It cools down for no particular reason too. It goes from 89 to 65 in seconds regardless of applications usage that I do. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went on and opened the Macbook, detached the ventilator fan, cleaned it - there was a thick dust ball underneath it somewhere, returned everything back and voila! Rarely goes over 80C now.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your Activity Monitor, it's tough to say what your CPU is doing.  However, a 24 degree temp swing in a couple of seconds is a lot.

Have you tried AHT (Apple Hardware Test)?

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257

My thinking is that you may have a bad temperature sensor (or it's getting bad info).

If that's the case, there are folks who repair things like this, or it just may be a good reason to upgrade your Mac.  There is a guy in NY that does really good work (I am not affiliated) repairing these boards:  https://mailin.repair/

Comment: Thanks! I will try that and tell you if it shows something important at all. What do you think the overheating is? I don't have it usually much over 90 Celsius, so it might not be a problem at all.

Comment: A resistor or capacitor may have died and it's either a bad sensor or it's sending bad data to the sensor.  Until you get it diagnostic codes off of it, there's really no way to tell.

Comment: try adding your comment as answer though see how that goes. I don't think that sending my Macbook to America is a good idea though. Thanks for the advice......

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic no apple genius near you?

Comment: No, not in Serbia, no. We don't even have an Apple Store. Not one.

Comment: I went on opened the macbook, detached the ventilator fan, cleaned it,  - there was a thick dust ball underneath it somewhere, returned everything back and voila! Rarely goes over 80C now.